# How do I disable the Show Tab Bar menu option in Sierra apps?

Tags: nswindow, nsmenu, macos-sierra

I've got an app that uses a Toolbar in a NSWindow. I don't want users to be able to customize this toolbar for aesthetic reasons. In Sierra there's a new Menu option that gets inserted into "Menu > View" called `Show Tab Bar`. How do I disable this? Enabling it only seems to increase the tool bar's height as I don't have extra labels showing under the icons.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On 10.12, you need to now set the following when the window is created as Tab Bar is now available by default:

```
[NSWindow setAllowsAutomaticWindowTabbing: NO];
```

The answer is the same in Swift and SwiftUI

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    NSWindow.allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing = false
}
```

Note that the call is made on the class `NSWindow` not on an instance of `NSWindow`

Comment: On 10.15 this method no longer seems to exist. Instead you can set the `tabbingMode` of the window to `.disallowed`. Specifically adding `window.tabbingMode = .disallowed` to the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of the `NSApplicationDelegate` seems to work.

Comment: The above comment is not true, it seems like they may have been trying to call `allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing` on an instance of a window rather than on NSWindow the class. In swift and swiftui you can still call `NSWindow.allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing = false` to remove these items entirely in all app windows rather than disabling them for individual windows.

Answer (score 33):

You can also do this on IB, on the Window’s attributes inspector

[image: NSWindow attribute inspector]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me.

Comment: where exactly this screen is located at?

Comment: You can also do it programmatically using the following code ```window.tabbingMode = NSWindowTabbingModeDisallowed```

Answer (score 5):

To disable tabbing on individual windows call `setTabbingMode:`

```
if([window respondsToSelector:@selector(setTabbingMode:)]) {
    // this particular window doesn't support tabbing in Sierra.
    [window setTabbingMode:NSWindowTabbingModeDisallowed];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to compile against the latest frameworks, you can use the following code in your NSWindowsController sub classes:

Swift:

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
     if NSAppKitVersionNumber > 1500 {
        self.window?.setValue(2, forKey: "tabbingMode")
     }
 }
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    if (NSAppKitVersionNumber > 1500) {
        [self.window setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"tabbingMode"];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `NSAppKitVersion.current.rawValue > NSAppKitVersion.macOS10_12.rawValue` with Swift 4

Comment: @ctietze: my answer os only relevant when using older versions of Xcode and Swift

Answer (score 4):

Swift solution:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    if #available(OSX 10.12, *) {
        tabbingMode = .disallowed
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, if you have an app delegate, add the line `window.tabbingMode = .disallowed` after the NSWindow has been created.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

In your `NSWindowController`:

```
self.window?.tabbingMode = .disallowed
```