# Hide NSWindow New tab button

Tags: cocoa, tabs, nswindow, nsdocument, macos-sierra

In macOS 10.12 there is a new tab bar that is added to NSWindows for NSDocument apps. You can prevent the toolbar from appearing (see [How do I disable the Show Tab Bar menu option in Sierra apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399553/)). But how to remove the "+" button for adding new Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the AppKit release notes, returning `false` for responding `newWindowForTab(_:)` action message in a NSDocumentController subclass disables "+" button in the tab bar.

```
override func responds(to aSelector: Selector!) -> Bool {

    if #available(OSX 10.12, *) {
        if aSelector == #selector(NSResponder.newWindowForTab(_:)) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return super.responds(to: aSelector)
}
```

See "**New Button**" section in the [AppKit Release Notes for macOS 10.12](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Depends of your Application functionality you may subclass **NSDocumentController** and return empty array for **documentClassNames** property.

```swift
class MyDocumentController: NSDocumentController {

   override var documentClassNames: [String] {
      return [] // This will disable "+" plus button in NSWindow tab bar.
   }
}
```

Here is a documentation of the **documentClassNames** property:

> **documentClassNames**
> An array of strings representing the custom document classes supported by this app.
>
> The items in the array are `NSString` objects, each of which represents the name of a document subclasses supported by the app. The document class names are derived from the app’s `Info.plist`. You can override this property and use it to return the names of document classes that are dynamically loaded from plugins.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/1514988-documentclassnames)

And here is explanation how **documentClassNames** property affects **NSWindow** tab bar plus button appearance:

> **New Button**
>
> The plus button will be shown if `newWindowForTab:` is implemented in the responder chain. `NSDocumentController` informally implements `newWindowForTab:`, but only returns YES from `respondsToSelector:` for this selector if the `self.documentClassNames.count > 0` and if the app has a default new document type. In other words, it only responds to it if `NSDocument` has at least one registered document class name which can be edited.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just set ‘Tabbing Mode’ to Disallowed in Interface Builder for your NSWindow.

[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder with Tabbing Mode set to Disallowed for a Window]

Comment: It disables all the window tabbing feature. Not only the add new button...

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
@IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {}
```

into this

```
@IBAction func myButton(_ sender: Any?) {}
```

This will hide the plus button. The tabbing still works

Comment: That makes no sense. Where would the first declaration even exist, so that I can change it?