# Remove 'Show/Hide tab bar' menu item

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

The latest version of macOS Sierra adds a 'Show/Hide tab bar' menu item to the 'View' menu.

[image: View menu item]

It does this dynamically.

My application already includes its own tab bar using the [MMTabBarView](https://github.com/MiMo42/MMTabBarView) library. I would prefer to continue using this library as it gives me backwards compatibility with tabs, plus the ability to do some customization to tabs.

I'm not seeing anything in apples [NSDocument](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocument) or [NSDocumentController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller) documentation on removing this menu item.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can remove it?

NOTE: I do not want to simply disable it, I am looking to remove it completely. (Or I guess not have it added in the first place).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable the Show Tab Bar menu option in Sierra apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399553/how-do-i-disable-the-show-tab-bar-menu-option-in-sierra-apps)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Interface Builder, open the attributes of your `NSWindow` and you'll see an option called "Tabbing Mode". Set it to Disallowed.

Comment: Ahhhh, the window itself. I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: In the SwiftUI you can do `window.tabbingMode = .disallowed`

Comment: For `Xamarin.Forms` applications we need to do this in the `AppDelegate` creation of the window and include `TabbingMode= NSWindowTabbingMode.Disallowed`. Making the changes in Xcode has no effect since we are using our own `NSWindow`.